# How to update react-i18next language based on a state?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I know how to change react-i18next language, but this change would only be valid for the current session or device.

So, when changing the locale, I update i18next first to provide an immediate ux feedback and then make an api call to update the user profile in my database.

```js
export async function useLocale(locale: Locale) {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const { updateProfile }= userService();
  i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
  return updateProfile({locale})
}
```

Now, how to make sure i18next fetches the locale from the user state on the next connection? My user state is stored in zustand:

```js
export const userStore = create(() => ({ name: "Joe", locale: "en" }));
```

The i18nconfig is:

```js
const languages = {
  EN: "en",
  FR: "fr",
};

const langDetectorOptions = {
  order: ["cookie", "localStorage", "navigator"],
  lookupCookie: "locale",
  lookupLocalStorage: "locale",
  caches: ["localStorage", "cookie"],
  excludeCacheFor: ["cimode"],
  checkWhitelist: true,
};

const resources = {
  en: { translation: en },
  fr: { translation: fr },
};

export default i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: languages.EN,
    detection: langDetectorOptions,
    fallbackLng: languages.EN,
    keySeparator: ".",
    whitelist: [languages.EN, languages.FR],
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement a custom language detector: https://www.i18next.com/misc/creating-own-plugins.html#languagedetector